# Fluent NHibernate asp.net MVC caching

Tags: ajax, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, datatable

Having problems with my ASP.NET MVC2 project. I'm using Fluent NHibernate as ORM, and I really  like it. The problems that I have is with caching(I think). I have for example a JQuery DataTable that is getting data with ajax from the database through a controller. The DataTable lists different stuff from the database, If I remove or add some posts, the data doesent seem to update, even if the calls are getting made and NHibernate does what it is supposed to do(I think).

The data only updates as it should If I rerun the project(programming locally), but sometimes even that doesent work.

Is caching the problem? Is it NHibernate caches or the browser?

Comment: Are you seeing this in IE only? For example try it in Firefox/Chrome. IE caches ajax requests quite aggressively. Also after you add a post, can you check the database and see if the data is updated.

Comment: I see it in chrome and FF. The thing is that I am testing this by adding a post directly to the database, not through the application. So the database is correctly updated.

Comment: You will need to do it through the application to allow nHibernate to see the data, otherwise the data is not available to nHibernate. You would have to Clear() the cache to force nHibernate to return to the database.

Comment: Yeah you must be right. Because it works if I add new users(and login with them) which I have functions for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is updated at the database and not through the application, nHibernate will not know about the data, and when queried for again by a List(), or Load() will not return to the database to acquire the full data set.

Suggestions here are:

- For this testing create some means of
  putting data in the database via
  nHibernate
- Or whilst in a testing
  stage, have the service method that
  is being called by jQuery Clear the
  cache each time, thus forcing
  nHibernate back to the database with
  each request.

This can be done completely using ISession.Clear(), or the known objects could be evicted using Evict().

**Not** really a go-live option though because it is advantages to have nHibernate caching data.

Comment: What if I have some other application updating the database? If so NHibernate won't know about it. The only solution to that is to clear the cache?

Comment: Absolutely, or make your nHibernate session last only for the duration of the HTTP request so that [each request](http://ryanlanciaux.com/ryanlanciaux/post/NHibernate-Session-Per-Request.aspx) gets a fresh cut.